# Anchor link to input box (same behaviour as label for="...")

Tags: html, forms, input, accessibility, anchor

I need to set an anchor tag using eg. `<a href="#firstname">Test</a>` to have the same behaviour as a `<label for="firstname">Blah</label>`, by putting the cursor inside the input box.

### Steps to reproduce

The Form Input has an id="firstname", the link has an href="#firstname".

1. Keyboard Tab to the link
2. Hit Enter

### Expected Behaviour

1. Focus is on the text input
2. Input is highlighted
3. Typing enters data into the field

### Actual Behaviour

- ✅ Chrome: Works.
- ❌ Firefox: Field is not highlighted and typing does not enter data into the field.
- ❌ Safari: Field is highlighted, but typing does not enter data into the field.

### JSFiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/78vmnxdy/

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: can you post fiddle please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that with simple `focus()` function of jQuery

jQuery:

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    $("#inputText").focus();
});
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Lrmqr/

Hope this is what you are looking for!